# Same style for QPushButton and QToolButton during mouse-over

Tags: qt, hover, styles, qpushbutton, qtoolbutton

Is it possible to make QPushButton and QToolButton look identical during mouse-over, i.e. the look and feel for hover events?

I don't use custom stylesheets, but there is a global application setting:

```
QtGui.QApplication.setStyle("plastique")
```

I'm looking for something like "propagate" the current (system-default) mouse-over-stylesheet of a QPushButton to a QToolButton. By default, a QPushButton will be highlighted during mouse-over, while a QToolButton does nothing at all.

Environment: Qt 4.8.6, running on Linux CentOS 6 and Windows 7

Comment: So basically you are saying you just want to disable hover effect on QPushButton, this isnt actually anything to do with QToolButton right?

Comment: No, I would like to **enable** the hover effect on QToolbutton (to look like a QPushbutton).

Comment: The easiest way is going to be to create a custom style sheet, giving similar styles to both buttons. The system style behaviors tend to be baked in, and not easily manipulated when they don't have an API call.

Answer (score 1):

Taking Nicolas answer as starting point, I created an own CSS style sheet:

```
QPushButton,QToolButton {

  background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #fdfbf7, stop: 1 #cfccc7);
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #8f8f91;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 4px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

QToolButton[popupMode="1"] {

  padding-right: 18px;
}

QToolButton::menu-button {

  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #8f8f91;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  /* 16px width + 2 * 1px for border = 18px allocated above */
  width: 16px;
}

QPushButton:hover,QToolButton:hover {

  border-top-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #b2afaa, stop: 0.5 #4847a1, stop: 1 #7e7cb6);
  border-radius: 1px;
  border-top-width: 3px;
  border-bottom-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #7e7cb6, stop: 0.5 #4847a1, stop: 1 #b2afaa);
  border-bottom-width: 3px;
  background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #e4e0e1, stop: 1 #cfcbcd);
}

QPushButton:pressed,QToolButton:pressed {

  background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #cfcbcd, stop: 1 #e4e0e1);
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #8f8f91;
}

QPushButton:focus,QToolButton:focus {

  outline: none;
}
```

To apply the style, I used the following PyQT code snippet:

```
cssFile = os.path.join(self.installDir, "etc", "Buttons.css")
with open(cssFile, "r") as fh:
    cssStyleSheet = "".join(fh.readlines())

    for i in range(self.verticalLayout.count()):
        widget = self.verticalLayout.itemAt(i).widget()
        if isinstance(widget, QtGui.QPushButton) or isinstance(widget, QtGui.QToolButton):
            widget.setStyleSheet(cssStyleSheet)
        # Make Tool- and PushButton same height...
        if isinstance(widget, QtGui.QToolButton):
            widget.setMaximumHeight(self.firstPushButton.sizeHint().height())
```

The resulting look and feel is almost identical to the default "plastique" style, if the application background color is set to "#ede9e3".

At first, I applied the style sheet to all Tool- and PushButtons (i.e. system default). But after this, all buttons in dialogs lost there default width. So I decided to apply the style only to the buttons inside of the vertical layout, which contains all involved buttons.